# What is Django on IronPython.Net Status?

Tags: asp.net, django, ironpython

I searched the web and stackoverflow, but unfortunately, have not found any definite answers on whether or not Django is properly supported in IronPython.Net.

At work, I have some tools I would love to develop in Django and Python, but from what I have read, Django is not really supported in IronPython.Net.

Please do correct me if I am wrong, but I would definitely love to get this working in a .Net environment.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not currently supported. Parts of it work and parts of it don't.

You can find a starting point at http://bitbucket.org/jdhardy/django-ipy-patches, but I really need to add some documentation.

Help getting it running would be appreciated!

Comment: thanks! That is very exciting to hear. I am currently at a beginner level in Python and still learning, but I would love to get involved one way or another!

Comment: I would recommend trying to run the Django tutorial (http://jdhardy.blogspot.com/2010/10/running-django-tutorial-on-ironpython.html for instructions), and if you have any issues, ask on the IronPython mailing list (see http://ironpython.net/support/).